# Can you specialise using statements?

Tags: c++

If I want some type to be specialised on its template parameter I generally use a struct:

```
template <bool value>
struct IsTrue;

template <>
struct IsTrue<true> : std::true_type {};

template <>
struct IsTrue<false> : std::false_type {};
```

An empty struct that gets its only functionality from inheritance isn't really that different from a `using` statement, so I was wondering, does something like template specialisation exist for `using` statements? Pseudocode of what I'm after below:

```
template <bool value>
using IsTrue;

template <>
using IsTrue<true> = std::true_type;

template <>
using IsTrue<false> = std::false_type;
```

Is something like this possible? What would it be called?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but if it is using a `using` statement like that is creating a *type alias* just the way `typedef` does.

Comment: Have a look at type aliasing http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: No, alias templates cannot be partially or explicitly specialized. And that's a good thing, because otherwise template argument deduction cannot look through it.

Comment: @T.C. thanks. Feel free to post as the answer. I thought this one might have been a long shot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, alias templates cannot be partially or explicitly specialized.

[An earlier design](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1406.pdf) did allow specialization, but the resulting semantics are rather...odd, at least viewed from today's angle. For example, in such a design, the following program would declare two *different* function templates:

```
template<class, class> class Meow {};
template<class T> using MeowInt = Meow<int, T>;
template<class> void f(Meow<int, T>);
template<class> void f(MeowInt<T>);
```

and this call would not compile because you wouldn't be able to deduce the template argument:

```
template<class T> using Purr = T;
template<class T> void f(Purr<T>);

f(42);
```